# Why I can not uninstall the software wine in my ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies, software-uninstall

This started when I want to remove wine from my ubuntu. after I run this command

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
```

I thought I had managed to remove the software, it did not. then display an error message on my ubuntu panel related to the software.

> An error occurred, please run package manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what wrong. the error message was: 'unknown error: ''("the cache has no package named 'wine-devel-i386'. this usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

I don't understand the meaning of the error message

[image: image problem]

Comment: Do you want to remove wine?

Comment: is the computer connected to the internet

Comment: In your image you were trying to remove wine-devel-i386 while in your question you said you want to remove wine? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try use two single commands:

`sudo apt-get remove wine`

`sudo apt-get purge wine`

This error means that the server, from which he was trying to download "*wine-devel-amd64*", is unavailable.

Comment: OP said they tried those commands

Comment: @Anwar Do you know, why Ubuntu wants install _wine-devel-amd64_ during removal?

Comment: Yes. I do suspect some. why?

Comment: @Anwar Can you tell me? I want to learn something.